# Monitor consuming too much power

Tags: mac, display, usb

I received this message:

[image]

and then my external monitor shut off.  Nothing else is plugged into my monitor and the monitor is plugged in to the wall outlet so the monitor should not be consuming much power from my mac.

For the USB-C cable that goes from my monitor to my mac, the end that plugs into the mac was quite hot.

It seems that one of the following is broken:

- Mac
- USB cable
- monitor

Any idea which one is the cause or how to figure it out?  I'll try swapping the things that I can...

Comment: Make / Model of Monitor and specific Mac model and year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the USB-C to HDMI cable fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Besides trying a different USB-C port or cable, you might also want to try a SMC Reset:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Make sure your Mac is running the most recent version of its current macOS as well.